# Need Help Pulling 100k Public Events using Graph API

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for a way to pull around 100k public events associated with a single Facebook User/Creator account using the Graph API.

All of the events are 'public' and are connected with the particular user account.  I want to fetch and store these on my database to better query and filter against.

When I try the Graph API Explorer (https://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/events), it obviously hangs when trying to pull this data.  I'm wondering if there's a way I can do this efficiently without upsetting Facebook or triggering any red flags or violating any Facebook terms of use.

Since the events are just public, I'm hoping it wouldn't be an issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try the Graph API Explorer (https://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/events), it obviously hangs when trying to pull this data.

Try using the limit parameter, and then use the paging-URLs the graph response provides to read the next chunk of data.